# How can one express $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}$ without using the square root of a square root?

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I was trying to review some analysis, and came across problem 3 from page 78 of Walter Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*.  As part of the problem, I wanted to try to write $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}$ without using the square root of a square root.  In other words, I wanted to express the number in the form $q_1+q_2{q_3}^s$, where $q_1, q_2, q_3, s \in \mathbb{Q}$ (or perhaps something similar).  I'm aware that this is probably a duplicate of another question, but I wasn't able to find it (I wasn't sure what to search for)...  Many thanks in advance!

Edit (my work so far):

I tried expressing it as the solution to the quartic $x^4-4x^2+2=0$, but this seemed futile...

Edit 2 (the original problem):

The original problem from the text states:

> If $s_1=\sqrt{2}$, and $$S_{n+1}=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{s_n}} (n=1,2,3,\ldots),$$
>   prove that $\{s_n\}$ converges, and that $s_n<2$ for $n=1,2,3,\ldots$.

The problem is from the 3rd chapter of the book, which talks about sequences and series. Rudin provides numerous theorems on this topic, such as the comparison, ratio, and root tests for convergence.

Comment: For those of us without quick access to Rudin, what's the original problem itself?

Comment: Yeah, the exact formulation of the problem could help. What exactly are we allowed to use?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: Sure, sorry about that.  The original problem states: If $s_1=\sqrt{2}$, and $$S_{n+1}=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{s_n}} (n=1,2,3,...),$$ prove that $s_n$ converges, and that $s_n<2$ for $n=1,2,3,...$.

Comment: I'll add this to the problem...

Comment: Ahhh, all right.  That makes more sense, and makes for an entirely different problem - you don't have to express $s_2$ any more simply to solve the original problem.  Hints: 1) Can you prove that if $s_n\lt 2$ then $s_{n+1}\lt 2$?  2) Can you prove that $s_{n+1}\gt s_n$?

Comment: I'm certain that you can't express it using only rationals and $\sqrt 2$ (because the polynomial you mentioned is irreducible over rationals and of degree $4>2$). I don't believe the form you mentioned is possible, either. If you still want an answer to the question, you might want to add algebraic number theory tag.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki There's apparently a [version available](http://faculty.ksu.edu.sa/fawaz/File282/Books/principles_of_mathematical_analysis_walter_rudin.pdf) but I can't speak to whether or not one should use it.

Comment: @tomasz It's not clear whether the form he mentioned is possible, since he could pick something like $s=1/4$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki:  That's alright, I'm able to solve the original problem (although many thanks for your hints).  I was really more interested in my original question, which puzzles me...

Comment: @Andrew: Not quite the same thing you asked about, but you might want to look at my comments about "square root of surds" (a standard topic in 19th century algebra texts) in this [3 March 2011 Math Forum archived post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=7397825).

Comment: One denesting is $\:\sqrt{2+\sqrt 2}\, =\, i^{1/4} + (-i)^{1/4}\ $

Comment: @BillDubuque:  That's pretty cool:))  Not exactly what I was looking for (it uses complex numbers), but definitely cool:))

Comment: If you want to throw in cube roots as well, then the real root of the cubic $-2-(3-i)x+(1+i)x^2+x^3=2\,i^{3/4}(1+x)$ is $x = \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}$, though I find Dubuque's result much nicer.

Comment: math.stackexchange.com/questions/1630586/how-is-sqrt-2-sqrt-2-sqrt-2-n-times-2-cos-%cf%80-2n1 had asked the same sometimes ago

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Short answer: you can't. Call your element $\alpha$. You want $\alpha$ to live in a field extension of the form $\mathbb{Q}(\beta^{1/4})$ for some $\beta \in \mathbb{Q}$. It's clear that $L = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is a degree 4 field extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ (you've written down a minimal polynomial).

One can check easily that $L$ is Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$ (i.e. you can check that $\sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2}} \in L$). But $\mathbb{Q}(\beta^{1/4})$ (for $\beta$ squarefree) is not.

Comment: The question was WITHOUT using the square root of a square root, which seems to be opposite of this.

Comment: OP wants $\alpha$ to be of the form $a + bc^{1/n}$. Since $\alpha$ has degree 4, $n$ would have to be 4; I'm proving that can't happen. (OP may be happy with a more general expression of $\alpha$ as a sum of a lot of roots; I think you will get a similar contradiction if you try that though.)

Comment: I think so, too, but it seems rather nontrivial to me (though I have only brief familiarity with algebraic number theory, so it wouldn't surprise me if I was wrong). These kinds of questions tend to have some methods fail quickly as you increase the number of summands.

Comment: I believe the galois group of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}})$ is cyclic. In particular it can't be a bi-quadratic extension, because the galois group would have to be Klein 4. I think this generalizes fairly easily to showing that it can't be contained in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{p_i})$ for some set of primes $p_i$. Because the galois group has no cyclic subgroup of order $4$.

Comment: @JacobSchlather You mean "no cyclic quotient of order $4$", not "no cyclic subgroup of order $4$". Otherwise, good comment!

Comment: @DavidSpeyer Yes, I worked through a few of the details after posting that and realized that what I needed was quotient. But fortunately the galois group is $\mathbb Z_2^n$ so the argument is still fine.

Answer (score 5):

For completeness's sake here is the solution to the original problem:

We first solve the equation
$$
\sqrt{2+\sqrt{x}}=x
$$
and the only real root $y$ is about 1.812. Now we have $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}\approx 1.847$. If we differentiate $\frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{x}}}{x}$ with respect to $x$, the derivative is always negative. So when $s_{n}\ge y$, $s_{n}$'s value would decrease under iteration until it is less than $y$, and when $s_{n}\le y$ it would increase, since on the interval $[0,y]$ the quotient is greater than $0$. This force the limit to be $y$.

Another way to see it is observing that 
$$
s_{n}=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{s_{n-1}}}, |s_{n+1}-s_{n}|=|\sqrt{2+\sqrt{s_{n}}}-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{s_{n-1}}}|=|\frac{\sqrt{s_{n}}-\sqrt{s_{n-1}}}{s_{n}+s_{n+1}}|
$$
therefore we have
$$
|\frac{s_{n+1}-s_{n}}{s_{n}-s_{n-1}}|=\frac{1}{|s_{n}+s_{n-1}||\sqrt{s_{n}}+\sqrt{s_{n-1}}|}\le \frac{1}{4}
$$
and the rest follows from contraction mapping theorem.

Comment: This inequality does not hold for all $x \le 2$.  It fails at $x = 1.9$, for example: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%282%2Fx%5E2+%2B+x%5E%28-3%2F2%29%29+-+1+at+x+%3D+1.9&dataset=&equal=Submit

Comment: Yes, there is an arithmetic mistake. The correct bound is $2^{-1/4}$, which is too small for it to be monotonely increasing. And judged from the graph it is also not monotonely increasing. I shall fix that.

Comment: Hopefully fixed.

Answer (score 1):

And then there is always trigonometry: $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}=2\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{8}\right)$.